# Matplotlib and numpy import don't work after pycharm 2019 optimize imports

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, optimization, pycharm

I used Pycharm 2019.1's import optimization on a full project and now the imports for matplotlib and numpy don't work.
Here is the full error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO/PycharmProjects/CSinternal/LearnIt.py", line 8, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\CSinternal\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 139, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\CSinternal\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\CSinternal\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\CSinternal\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\CSinternal\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\CSinternal\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 45, in <module>
    """)
RuntimeError: implement_array_function method already has a docstring
```

I'm new here and honestly don't know what this ( RuntimeError: implement_array_function method already has a docstring) means. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest to roll that import optimization back via git or what ever VCS you are using and apply the optimization file/directory wise. I'm using PyCharm myself but I haven't used this feature yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution for me appeared when I realized that I had imported torch as two different names in different files in the same project. By renaming them I got rid of the error. I suspect you might have a similar issue. Try running the code in a new project without any other files in the same project.